# UI becoming unresponsive after a particular number of results

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt

I am working on RCP based application,where I need to populate the the screen with lines of results.Now,my application works fine as soon as I have a small amount of data e.g 300 rows.After 300 rows If I click on the button "Show More" to display more results the UI becomes unresponsive.I did try with both `Display().getCurrent().asyncExec()` and `Display().getCurrent().syncExec()`.I dont get result as expected .Below is the code snippet.

```
private void setResults(final SearchResultData results) {
        int totalHits = 0;
        this.results = results;
        setMoreResultsBtnVisible(false);
        setResultHeadingText(offset, totalHits);
        if (results != null && !results.getResults().isEmpty()) {
            totalHits = results.getTotalHits();
            setResultHeadingText(offset, totalHits);
            final boolean showMore = offset < totalHits;
            Display.getCurrent().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scrolledResultList != null && !scrolledResultList.isDisposed()) {
                        populateList(results.getResults());
                        setMoreResultsBtnVisible(showMore);
                        scrolledResultList.layout();
                        resizeScrollableComposite();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `setResults` running in the UI thread or a background thread or Job?

Comment: It is running in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Any code you run in the UI thread will make the UI unresponsive until it finishes. Using `syncExec` or `asyncExec` from UI thread code doesn't help.

You need to put the long running code in a Eclipse `Job` or a background thread. You must then use `syncExec` or `asyncExec` just for the code which actually accesses UI controls (attempting to access controls directly will fail).